# COM Object vs Automation Object

Tags: com, automation, activex

I am creating a COM Object in Delphi XE2. I am trying to create the methods using safecall, but the default is stdcall.

When i use Automation Object is possible to use safecall.

For performance questions, i am using COM Object. Is it possible to use safecall on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `safecall` convention.
The only difference between `safecall` and `stdcall` is that `safecall` is suitable for exception-driven flow. That is, if your Delphi function is `safecall`, it can raise an exception, which will be catched internally and translated to the proper HRESULT.

By the way, there's no performance benefit with COM Object vs Automation object: although an Automation object supports the slower "[late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_COM_languages)" via [`IDispatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, its clients are not obliged to use it. Clients, which are able to use "early binding", can use it with Automation objects as well.

Comment: @PedroMagalhaes That was exactly what I was looking for coming to this thread. I wasn't sure what an "Automation Object" was.